# Cannot iterate 2 hashmaps in a hashmap

Tags: java, collections

I cannot iterate this structure (Java):

```
HashMap<HashMap<Integer, Integer>, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> last
    = new HashMap<HashMap<Integer, Integer>, HashMap<Integer, Integer>>();
```

These are the 2 HashMaps that I am adding into the first:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> arrival = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
HashMap<Integer, Integer> departure = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

Tried various loops, read a couple of articles but I cannot connect the dots to make it correct until now.

I want for example to be able to get/print the four integer values from the two HashMaps in the HashMap together in the loop.

Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful to know what information you are trying to model - what do these integers represent?

Comment: @RoryHunter probably numbers :) *scnr*

Comment: I'm making a program which takes the hours / minutes of bus departure and arrival as well (That's why I need 4 values). I want to iterate these four values in one data structure in order to be able to compare them later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't think it is a good idea to have a `HashMap` as a `key` in another `HashMap`. It looks like you are representing a map of key value pairs (arrival/destination?), you would be better off  creating an class just for that and adding that class to a `HashMap`. Using your current structure will cause more confusion than benefits.

That said, it *is* possible to loop through this.

One way to loop through a HashMap is to loop trhough its entry set. So if `h` is a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`, you loop as:

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : h.entrySet)
{
...
}
```

So, for a `HashMap<HashMap<Integer, Integer>, HashMap<Integer, Integer>>` called `last`

```
for(Map.Entry<HashMap<Integer, Integer>, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> entry : last.entrySet())
{
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> key = entry.getKey();
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> keyMapEntry : key.entrySet())
    {
        //Loop through the value HashMap. 
        //keyMapEntry.getKey() gives the key of the Hashmap that is the key in the 
        //original Hashmap, keyMapEntry.getValue() gives the value
    }

    HashMap<Integer, Integer> value = entry.getValue();
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> valueMapEntry : value.entrySet())
    {
        //Loop through the key HashMap
        //valueMapEntry.getKey() gives the key of the Hashmap that is the value in the 
        //original Hashmap, valueMapEntry.getValue() gives the value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I thought I am not using the correct data structure - I will just put the four values that I need to compare with other objects' values into an Array or Array List and will make a class which creates objects of this type when needed.

Comment: Or even better will put the values in Doubles in 1 HashMap with the ordinary check.